# using static variables as arguments in a method?

Tags: java, oop, methods, static, encapsulation

I'm a fresher to Java. These days I'm dealing with the OOP concepts. 
I'm stuck in here because I can't decide how to code in the method named **set** to complete my code.Here is my code,

```
class Date {
    private int year=1970;
    private int month=1;
    private int day=1;
    static int YEAR;
    static int MONTH;
    static int DAY;

    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year=year;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month=month;
    }
    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day=day;
    }

    public void printDate(){
        System.out.println(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
    }
    public void set(int field, int value){
        //


            //
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Date d1=new Date();
        d1.printDate();
        d1.set(Date.YEAR,2018);
        d1.set(Date.MONTH,04);
        d1.set(Date.DAY,18);
        d1.printDate();
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with the `set method` . How to code in the set method.Could anyone help me with this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say "I'm stuck" but never described a problem or error.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the problem right, you should first move `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY` to the `DateUnit` enum.

```
public enum DateUnit {
    YEAR, MONTH, DAY
}
```

And then make `set` method to accept `DateUnit unit` and `int value`.

```
public void set(DateUnit unit, int value) {
    switch (unit) {
        case YEAR: {
            year = value;
            break;
        }
        case MONTH: {
            month = value;
            break;
        }
        case DAY: {
            day = value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.set(DateUnit.YEAR,2018);
date.set(DateUnit.MONTH,04);
date.set(DateUnit.DAY,18);
```